# How to create a shortcut to IMCE File Browser?

Tags: 7

The File Browser link is different for each user, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/user/1/imce
http://example.com/user/10/imce
```

How can I create a shortcut to the File Browser which is good for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [me aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/me) module.

It turns:

```
http://example.com/user/10/imce
```

to:

```
http://example.com/user/me/imce
```

Answer (score 1):

For the current user /imce path should work:

```
http://example.com/imce
```

Answer (score 0):

This is default page provided by IMCE module, you can create your own menu callback which will call same page callback which is used by "user/[UID]/imce". To do this you can use [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Once you've done that, if required you can remove access to default page using [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

Here is example of how you can achieve this:

```
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  $items['custom-imce'] = array(
    'title' => 'File browser',
    'page callback' => 'MODULENAMW_imce_user_page',
    'access callback' => 'MODULENAMW_imce_user_page_access',
  );

  return $items;
}

function MODULENAMW_imce_user_page() {
  global $user;

  if (!empty($user->uid)) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'imce', 'inc/imce.page');
    imce_user_page($user);
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Please login to access this page.'), 'warning');
    drupal_goto('');
  }
}

function MODULENAMW_imce_user_page_access() {
  global $user;

  if (!empty($user->uid)) {
    return imce_user_page_access($user);
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```